# What is the ideal indexing strategy for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A friend and I are working on a new project that is using SQL Server. In the SQL that I've done past projects, I've always put indexes on any field that is used in a JOIN or a WHERE.

My friend has added them only when there has been a performance need for them. The idea being that there is a cost to maintaining the indexes, and you want to be sure that it is worth paying that cost. It is fair to say that some of the queries are not going to be used often, and also that some tables will be added to more actively than others.

I'm therefore looking for advice on what is the "best practice" for database indexes. What works well for you?

Comment: This question is very broad. Don't expect easy answers. You can make better _educated decisions_ if you understand: how the index structures work, how INSERT/UPDATES affect indexes, the impact of LOCKS and lock escalation, the principles of selectivity, the patterns of access of your data. _**But everything boils down to:** In a system of any significant size, index tuning is **an ongoing process** involving monitoring, profiling, bench-marking and experimental testing._

Comment: As a side note: I wonder if you really learnt anything? It looks like you simply accepted the answer that most closely matched and supported your own personal opinion. So it seems you were really just looking for someone to back you up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal preference goes to the **pro-active approach**: based on your queries, add indexes where needed. As you say, on fields that are involved in JOINs or WHEREs. Every index speeds up read-queries, but slows down writes (as every write needs to update the index). So for write-intensive table, other solutions (data-warehousing, replication...) might be needed.

The other approach, adding only indexes where performance requires them, is only valid if you do active monitoring, but even then has a **few drawbacks**:

- You will have to add an index to a table which is suffering performance issues. While the index is being added, your table is locked - and it's a heavily used table!
- Often when testing, test-data is several orders of magnitude smaller than the real data in the application. Bottlenecks risk being overlooked.

Comment: If you're working with tables so large that you're concerned about the performance impact of creating a new index _(assuming ofc a 24/7 system without maintenance windows?!)_: then it is significantly ***more important*** that the table is not bogged down with superfluous indexes (which may even contribute to locking problems).

Answer (score 7):

I would try to follow these guidelines:

- always have a **good** primary/clustering key - typically an `INT IDENTITY` - avoid GUID or large compound PK/CK. A well and thoughtfully chosen PK/CK will go a long way to help with performance overall. To thoroughly understand why, read all of Kimberly Tripp's [blog posts on clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Clustering-Key.aspx) choices.
- always index all foreign key columns - separately or together with other columns that make sense; this helps with JOIN performance
- other than that: **less is more**! Only add indices if you absolutely must - watch your system, profile your data load, see what the performance is, fine-tune, measure again. If an index help - keep it; if an index doesn't get used - toss it
- use the DMV's at hand (the [missing index DMV, and the unused indices DMV](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/08/SQL-Server---Find-missing-and-unused-indexes.aspx)) to get an idea for what indices might help, and which ones aren't being used at all...

Answer (score 2):

You want to put them only on those columns or *column groups* that have a lot of queries against them. You can get a lot of statistics from SQL Server to see what queries are being run against your tables, and SQL Server will even suggest indexes where you don't have them.

Here's a good link with some useful information and other links to good info. [SQL Server Index Checklist and tips](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1452)

Answer (score 1):

When designing indexes, follow these guidelines:

> - Use indexes on tables with numerous rows, on columns that are used in the
>     WHERE clause of queries or in table
>     joins, and on columns used in ORDER BY
>     and GROUP BY queries.
> - Avoid infrequently used indexes on frequently updated columns. In
>     addition, avoid having many indexes on
>     a table that is frequently updated.
>     Otherwise, you unnecessarily increase
>     the insert and update times of your
>     queries. To improve performance,
>     minimize the total width of the
>     indexed columns.
> - Use clustered and nonclustered indexes appropriately. Understand the
>     purpose of each and choose the correct
>     type for your scenario.
> - Use a covering index to reduce the query execution time of frequently
>     used statements. A covering index is a
>     nonclustered index that has all the
>     columns that come in a WHERE clause
>     and in the query column selection.

as according to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650692.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer for your question. It all comes down to the use of the tables. Monitoring the use of the table will tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details
```

Get to know your dynamic management views

And then go and use this sproc from this URL
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Index+Management/63937/

Also.. what homedude is saying about 'covered indexes' make sure that you understand the difference between covered indexes (SQL 2000) and indexes with the INCLUDE clause (SQL 2005 and newer)

Comment: I've found this table, but it is empty. Is there an option that needs to be enabled to fill it up?

Comment: I've never seen a production server with an empty DMW. Are you doing this in Dev? The other way to do this is to use SQL profiler (against production) to capture a trace and then to test this workload for performance using the database tuning advisor.  I usually be sure to NOT save it to a file / table while it's running, but then when the SQL profiler trace is done (when you hit stop) then you can save the trace results to a table. I Just think that it' s a lot better to do this at the end of the trace, instead of at the beginning of the trace.

Answer (score 1):

An index is best placed on a value that is **as unique as possible**. It is, for instance, *useless* to place an index on a column where 50% of that column is value 'A', and another 50% of the column has a value 'B'.

That way, the table will scan **at least 50% of the records** before selecting the right values.

So **best practice** is to place an index on the *most unique columns*, and only those columns that are used to select queries with.

**example:** if you were to create a select for a typical "Login", you would put an index on "Username" column, as you make sure the username is unique.

Comment: I edited my solution just before you wrote your comment i think. I was reading it over and saw exactly what you just mentioned.

Comment: Thumb rules can get under hammer - indexes can be used to retrieve data, too - so, even if you have 50-50 data, certain queries can benefit from an index - for example COUNT(*) ... WHERE ... = 'A' will have to read only the index. So it is not, necessarily, useless.