# How to create Index for this scenario in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing

What is the best Index to this `Item table` for this following query

```
select 
    tt.itemlookupcode,
    tt.TotalQuantity,
    tt.ExtendedPrice,
    tt.ExtendedCost,
    items.ExtendedDescription,
    items.SubDescription1,
    dept.Name,
    categories.Name,
    sup.Code,
    sup.SupplierName

from 
    #temp_tt tt

left join HQMatajer.dbo.Item items
on items.ItemLookupCode=tt.itemlookupcode

left join HQMatajer.dbo.Department dept
ON dept.ID=items.DepartmentID

left join HQMatajer.dbo.Category categories
on categories.ID=items.CategoryID

left join HQMatajer.dbo.Supplier sup
ON sup.ID=items.SupplierID

drop table #temp_tt
```

I created Index like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JFC_ItemLookupCode_DepartmentID_CategoryID_SupplierID_INC_Description_SubDescriptions] ON [dbo].[Item]
(
    [DBTimeStamp] ASC,
    [ItemLookupCode] ASC,
    [DepartmentID] ASC,
    [CategoryID] ASC,
    [SupplierID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   
    [Description],
    [SubDescription1]
)
```

But in Execution plan when I check the index which picked another index. That index having only `TimeStamp column`.

What is the best index for this scenario to that particular table.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152272/what-is-the-ideal-indexing-strategy-for-sql-server

Comment: @Hadi Unfortunately that question is far too broad and the answers suffer by having unqualified narrow applicability as a result. Entire books have been written on the subject of index tuning and it would be dangerous to consider that particular Q&A to be a substitute. (This question is much more specific, and yet it is still bordering on being too broad.)

Answer (score 2):

First column in index should be part of filtration else Index will not be used. In your index first column is `DBTimeStamp` and it is not filtered in your query. That is the reason your index is not used.

Also in covering index you have used `[Description],[SubDescription1]` but in query you have selected `ExtendedDescription,items.SubDescription1` this will have additional overhead of `key/Rid lookup`

Try alerting your index like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JFC_ItemLookupCode_DepartmentID_CategoryID_SupplierID_INC_Description_SubDescriptions] ON [dbo].[Item]
(
    [ItemLookupCode] ASC,
    [DepartmentID] ASC,
    [CategoryID] ASC,
    [SupplierID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   
    [ExtendedDescription],
    [SubDescription1]
)
```

Having said that all still optimizer go for scan or choose some other index based on data retrieved from `Item` table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised your index isn't used. `DBTimeStamp` is likely to be highly selective, and is not referenced in your query at all.

You might have forgotten to include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query which was intended reference `DBTimeStamp`. But even then your query would probably need to scan the entire index. So it may as well scan the actual table.

The only way to make that index 'look enticing' would be to ensure it includes ***all*** columns that are used/returned. I.e. You'd need to add `ExtendedDescription`. *The reason this can help is that indexes typically require less storage than the full table. So it's faster to read from disk. But if you're missing columns (in your case `ExtendedDescription`), then the engine needs to perform an additional lookup onto the full table in any case.*

I can't comment why the `DBTimeStamp` column is preferred - you haven't given enough detail. But perhaps it's the `CLUSTERED` index?

Your index would be almost certain to be used if defined as:

```
(
    [ItemLookupCode] ASC --The only thing you're actually filtering by
)
INCLUDE (
    /* Moving the rest to include is most efficient for the index tree.
       And by including ALL used columns, there's no need to perform
       extra lookups to the full table.
    */
    [DepartmentID],
    [CategoryID],
    [SupplierID],
    [ExtendedDescription],
    [SubDescription1]
)
```

Note however, that this kind of indexing strategy 'Find the best for each query used' is unsustainable.

- You're better off finding 'narrower' indexes that are appropriate multiple queries.
- Every index slows down INSERT and UPDATE queries.
- And indexes like this are impacted by more columns than the preferred 'narrower' indexes.

Index choice should focus on the *selectivity* of columns. I.e. Given a specific value or small range of values, *what percentage of data is likely to be selected* based on your queries?

In your case, I'd expect `ItemLookupCode` to be ***unique per item*** in the `Items` table. In other words indexing by that *without any includes* ***should be sufficient***. However, since you're joining to a temp table that theoretically *could include **all** item codes*: in some cases it might be better to scan the `CLUSTERED INDEX` in any case.